# Struct data assignment

Tags: matlab, struct

I am trying to calculate a distance for struct data type.

The distance method is:

```
 function ssd=distances(x, c)
   m=size(x,1);
   ssd = zeros(m, k);
   k=size(c,1);

  for i= 1:k
   z = bsxfun(@minus,x, c(i,:));
   ssd(:,i) = sqrt(z(:).^2,2);
 end
```

Then I have `c` which is a random number produced from the formula below:

```
for i=1:20
  pop(i).Position=unifrnd(2,2,4);
  pop(i).dist=distances(x= data,pop(i).Position=c);
end
```

x = data is 100x2.

The issue is when I call the distance method it does not accept the passed argument, `pop(i).position`.

Comment: Which argument? Also, you're using a variable `k` that's not defined anywhere that I can see. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Why do you have `x = ` and `=c` in your function call? What about `distances(data, pop(i).Position)`?

Comment: @Suever , yes , it is jut for explaining that x is the data , and c is pop(i).position

Comment: What is your actual error message?

Comment: @ Suever  the error is :   Error using sqrt
Too many input arguments.

Comment: the error is in   pop(i).dist=distances(x= data,pop(i).Position=c);

Answer (score 0):

Several errors and suggestions I can make:

1. The `sqrt` function only accepts a **single input parameter**.  You are specifying two input parameters.
2. You also aren't calculating the SSD right.  When you are performing `z = bsxfun(...);` you are simply calculating the component-wise distances between the `data` and your input query point `c(i, :)`.  You have to **sum** all of the component-wise distances as well.  That's probably why your `sqrt` function call is wrong because you probably meant to add a `sum` in addition to `sqrt` as well:

   ```
   ssd(:, i) = sqrt(sum(z.^2, 2));
   ```

   BTW, sum of square differences traditionally does not include the `sqrt` operation.... that's why it's called **sum** of **square** differences.
3. Also this code in your main loop doesn't make any sense:

   ```
   pop(i).dist=distances(x= data,pop(i).Position=c)
   ```

   My guess is that you are coming from a Python background where you can specify inputs as key-value pairs.  Don't do that.  Just do:

   ```
   pop(i).dist = distance(data, pop(i).Position);
   ```
4. This code `pop(i).Position=unifrnd(2,2,4);` will generate a 4 x 4 matrix between the values of 2 and 2... which doesn't make sense.  You probably wanted to generate a `4 x 2` matrix to match the number of features that your data has.  Use something else and make the range of random numbers larger.  To get this to `4 x 2` specify an additional argument.  Something like this could work:

   ```
   pop(i).Position = unifrnd(2, 10, 4, 2);
   ```

Comment: I have made the changes that you suggest , but still have error Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.

Comment: z = bsxfun(@minus,x, c(i,:));

Comment: Check the edit. Especially #4.  Your call to `unifrnd` does not make sense at all.